# How to change the font family of a TextInput with secureTextEntry?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have some TextInputs to put passwords, when the secureTextEntry is false the font family changes without problem, but when it is true it takes another font by default:

With SecureTextEntry true:

[image]

With SecuretTextEntry false:

[image]

This is my TextInput

```js
<TextInput
    style={stylesLoginScreen.inputPassword}
    placeholder="Tu contraseña"
    onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
    secureTextEntry={this.state.hidePassword}
    placeholderTextColor={'white'}
    // autoCapitalize={'none'}
/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native - unable to change font when secureTextEntry is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64396505/react-native-unable-to-change-font-when-securetextentry-is-set)

Comment: which react-native version do you use?

Comment: No, i am new in React Native, i can't use a hook in my class component i think.

Comment: @MahdiN I'm not sure, but i think i use the latest version

Comment: @Marc There is a bug in react-native version 0.63.3 that lead to have a wrong fontFamily when using secureTextEntry. This bug was corrected in version 0.63.4 (You can read more in [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30123)). So check your react-native version in package.json and if it's 0.63.3 I recommend that you upgrade to 0.63.4

Comment: @MahdiN Thanks, is there another way to do it without having to change the react version? Could I change the default font of the project right?

Comment: @Marc people in the github issue suggested [this solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30123#issuecomment-711076098) you can try it but it didn't work for me

Comment: @MahdiN The above solution worked for me. I am using typescript and react-native version is 0.64.0. It was giving me some ts error {Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)}. but i put //@ts-ignore to ignore that ts issue

Comment: @zilleabbas good it worked for you but remember that basically this is a bug in react native so it will be corrected in one of the next releases and you will not need this workaround anymore

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and my problem was solved through the use of useRef hook, I can't find the link to the post that helped me, so I am going to paste my code here. My email field style would appear perfect but the password font style would change on toggling between secureTextEntry to true and false. Below code helped me.

```
const inputRef: any = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef && inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.setNativeProps({
        style: {fontFamily: props.inputStyle.fontFamily},
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

And adding adding ref={inputRef} to the TextInput as

```
<TextInput ref={inputRef}.../>
```